# Importing classes from dependencies to JBPM process in JBPM 7.23

Tags: jbpm

Currently I am trying to import some classes in JBPM process, which are required in script task. And I am not able to add it through jbpm-console. I don't see the option of adding imports. This was possible in jbpm 6.5. Am I missing something..?

Answer (score 0):

You can import it in the script. I also do not see it in the new modeler import for the whole process model.

Comment: can you please tell me how can I import in the script?

Comment: Just like in a java file:
`import com.mycompany.myclass;`

Script is Activity/Task that you put in the jbpm modeller(User task, Script Task . .)

Answer (score 0):

Importing dependencies should be under settings in a jBPM project.

[image]

Comment: Thanks K.Nicholas for response. I have added my dependency jar from there. But in script tasks I am using some of the classes from dependencies, but it is showing error that something like class not found. I have added import entries manually by editing xml.
Something like following
      <drools:import name="org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser"/>
      <drools:import name="org.json.simple.JSONObject"/>
under  tag      <bpmn2:extensionElements>
But I am not sure this is the correct way of doing it or not.

Comment: Another way to add the JAR is from the Admin console (the gear icon shown above).  That UI lets you upload artifacts to the repository that you can then use via "Add from Repository" above.  This helps ensuring that the dependency is specified exactly

Answer (score 0):

You can add imports on process level setting (where process variables are defined).
[image]

[image]